# Polymer custom element naming convention feature/bug

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In polymer documentation they said

> By specification, the custom element's name **must contain a dash
>   (-)**.

So I make a custom element with name `custom-element`. Generally, everyone do that. But suddenly I got a doubt that **can we have a dash at the ends?**

Then I tried with `customelement-` and `-customelement`.

I wondered that having **dash(-)** at **right side end is working.** But having **dash(-)** at **left side end is not working.**

Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: The following link explain clearly. Try to understand
[Read this article](https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/how-should-i-name-my-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's working as expected.

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#prod-potentialcustomelementname) your element need to have a dash in its name (e.g `<my-tabs>`). That way you're forced to add a namespace which avoids conflicts with existing elements. A valid custom element name is a sequence of characters name that meets all of the following requirements

```
[a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*
```

where PCENChar:=

```
"-" | "." | [0-9] | "_" | [a-z] | #xB7 | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x203F-#x2040] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#prod-potentialcustomelementname

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unable to upvote as daily limit reached